# How to log-in to ssh without password? Note I do not have root previledge of server

Tags: ssh

I can only login to server as a non-root user. How can I make ssh login password-less?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want to try RSA public-key auth.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Here is a detailed method, and it depends on whether your ssh server allow rsa public key auth.